# CountDown is Not Working Correctly in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm facing a problem with a count down.

I want to restart the count down from **4 seconds**, every time when the timer starts.

For `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)`, what I get is **0, 3, 2, 1**, for the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)` part of code, it prints the count down quickly and in `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8)` it goes into **-1, -2** too.

**Code**

```
private Timer _timer;
private int _countSeconds;        

public CameraViewModel() {

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), () =>
{
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    _countSeconds = 4;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    return false;
});

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), () =>
{
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    _countSeconds = 4;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    return false;
});

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8), () =>
{
    // above code used here again
    return false;
});
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _countSeconds--;

    CountDown = _countSeconds;

   if (_countSeconds == 0)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}

#region Bindable Properties

private string _countDown;
public string CountDown
{
    get => _countDown;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _countDown, value);
}
#endregion
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Do you just want to countdown from 4 to 0?

Comment: @Jason yes. it should restart every time in `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(), () => { ... }`

Comment: see my answer below - this is basic C# and has nothing specific to do with Xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to countdown from 4..1 and reset

create a class level variable or property for your COunter

```
int Counter = 4;
```

create a single timer - there is no need for multiple timers

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Start();
```

when your timer fires

```
void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine(Counter);
        Counter--;

        if (Counter < 0) Counter = 4;
}
```

Comment: another user already gave you a lengthy explanation of the problem